# getting name value pairs(in decoded format) from the posted form

Tags: android, http, forms, https, httpwebrequest

we are working on developing plugin for k9-email client for android os... i want to get the name value pairs back in the decodedd format from the posted form..

when i open the mail after clicking "show original" on gmail then following is displayed...like..

```
input name=3D"DefaultZDM" value=3D"https://voltage-pp-0000.july.co=
m/zdr" type=3D"hidden">
        input name=3D"ZFRDesignatedRecipient" value=3D"daphnebarretto@gmai=
l.com" type=3D"hidden">
        div style=3D"width: 1px; max-width: 1px; min-height: 1px; max-heig=
ht: 1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px;">
            pre style=3D"width: 1px; max-width: 1px; min-height: 1px; max-=
height: 1px; overflow: hidden; padding: 5px;">               =20
-----BEGIN VOLTAGE SECURE BLOCK V2-----
pt7tH1g22PVBtplPHn6zQgtRS2LFWbVavN5ZMOWs+S/x5OiPmWNy+Na8Xek9ICpE
3cm5xa5dIYvgYiYLbk8C0CuTd6koONPGs2IH2IQhm32phDpafXoa/1n3xOcfuuSB
v79H3sWZtW7EKy2hblpKi+0Y9KOZvpaL7nSd6tz9EVrA7XBa9nM1fvpBWvOsWIkA
VeYgMgjMFpLOVsastOqj3eJW7Jp+u4cm5n8PWAI4T9YuETtP/waOvYF8TAMI8Vey
3y09ZmJ2BS9VLhPKMJHSod6cYeSbD1gRwPoVp+AybnKz+BeBzd2DjBHS+sbd7/Va
Gn1beoCwfdPAteYxWcFShb6Sznw7whlZDyDnwtCwqrcHOpHIYkzXp4N5/4qzUzof
/QyBRY35rSciihyKqdo=3D
-----END VOLTAGE SECURE BLOCK V2-----

            </pre>
        </div>
    </font>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
    =20
</div>
</div>
```

from the above, input tags, i want to get the 
`DefaultZDM="https://voltage-pp-0000.july.com/zdr"` and
`ZFRDesignatedRecipient="daphnebarretto@gmail.com"`

thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to use a regular expression to find your matches.  Below is an example of how to use a regular expression to break a string at 160 characters, but you could easily modify it with:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("DefaultZDM\" value=3D\"(.*)\"|ZFRDesignatedRecipient\" value=3D\"(.*)\""
```

I'm certain I do NOT have that pattern correct, but it's a start.  That would match your desired value pairs and you could assign them to variables in your code.

```
protected ArrayList<String> splitMsg(SmsMessage smsMessage) {
        ArrayList<String> smt;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{1,160}");
        Matcher regexMatcher = p.matcher(smsMessage.getMsgBody());
        smt = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (regexMatcher.find()) {
            smt.add(regexMatcher.group());
        }
        return smt;
    }
```

Comment: thanks your ans is correct but their is another way of doing same..i.e

Comment: (continue above comment) add external Jsoup.jar file to your android project it have the APIs of parsing html

Comment: @saurabh patil That's awesome.  I'll give it a look.